# Access SQL select count number of specific field from one table join another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have these two table in my access file (I make it simple)
Table 1: Users:

```
ID        User_Code       User_Name
==        =========       ==========
1         1111            John
2         2222            Alex
3         3333            Tom
```

Table 2 GB:

```
ID        User_Code       First(is Boolean)
==        =========       =================
1         1111            Yes
2         2222            Yes
3         1111            Yes
4         1111            Yes
```

I want a SQL query that result like this table:

```
User_Name       CountNum
=========       =========
John            3
Alex            1
Tom             0
```

I know I must use inner join and distinct and count function but don't know exactly how???
I appreciate for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear where the `distinct` comes in.  This is just a `join` and `group by`:

```
select u.user_name, count(gb.user_code)
from users as u left join
     gb
     on u.user_code = gb.user_code
group by u.user_name;
```

Note:  The user of `user_code` for the `join` key is suspect.  The `Users` table has an `id`.  Normally that would be used for the `join`.

Answer (score 0):

You want left join instead of inner join and there is no need for distinct...

```
select u.user_name, count(g.user_code)
from users u left join gb g
     on u.user_code = g.user_code
group by u.user_name
```